# Error al consumir JSON. app.js RESTful Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

Tengo el siguiente proyecto, bastante simple, que consume el siguiente objeto JSON obtenido desde un servicio web local.

```
{"nombre":"Miguel","id":1,"profesion":"Desarrollador"}
```

Mi app.js esta asi:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulApp/rest/lista/verificar"
    }).then(function(data){
        $('verificar-nombre').append(data.nombre);
        $('verificar-id').append(data.id);
        $('verificar-profesion').append(data.profesion);
    });
});
```

Y el index asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Prueba Angular</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/main/webapp/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="verificar-nombre">Nombre</p>
        <p class="verificar-id">ID</p>
        <p class="verificar-profesion">Profesion</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Al momento de ejecutar el proyecto, la consola de chrome devuelve error 404 con la siguiente informacionn:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente y por lo que pueden ver esta todo de forma correcta, alguna idea por que el index no encuentra mi app.js?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @miguel si tu index.html es el que carga el archivo app.js deberías de referenciar de la siguiente manera: <script src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: Ahora si encuentra app.js pero no carga los datos recuperados desde el endpoint.

Comment: la carpeta (rest) si existe?

Answer (score 0):

en esta parte: "url: "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulApp/rest/lista/verificar", en caso de que "verificar" sea tu json no está demás que agregues la extensión ".json", además a los selectores les falta el punto, ya que, los estas buscando en base a sus clases:

```js
$('.verificar-nombre').append(data.nombre);
```

Y te recomiendo que emplees un framework js que tengas bien definido, JQuery o Angular.